# Value not yet initialized in parent class when calling method from base class

Tags: typescript, class

We have the following structure

```
abstract class testParent{
    constructor(){
        console.log(this.doSomething());
    }

    abstract doSomething():string;
}

class testChild extends testParent{
    private x:string = 'someValue';

    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    doSomething():string{
        return this.x;
    }
}

const y = new testChild();
```

And we noticed that the string x is not yet initialized so it returns undefined. But we would like to have this structure. What are some ways to deal with this problem?

We thought of one solution

```
abstract class testParent{
    constructor(){
        this.initialize();
        console.log(this.doSomething());
    }

    abstract initialize():void;

    abstract doSomething():string;
}

class testChild extends testParent{
    private x:string = '';

    initialize():void{
        this.x = 'someValue';
    }

    doSomething():string{
        return this.x;
    }
}


const y = new testChild();
```

But this feels quite hacky.

Comment: Could you add more realistic example? Why would you do this in constructor?

Comment: We would like the parent class to be more of a template that makes sure that we have the correct data to send to the database. We put it in the constructor so that future programmers don't have to call that method without knowing about it's existance.

Comment: You can invoke the required action after "template" is already created (factory or whatever other solution). Programmers won't have to do it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access `x` before it is initialized.
Even though you're probably not aware, in reality your constructor does this:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.x = 'someValue';
    }
```

which means `doSomething()` is called with `this.x` not yet being assigned a value.

Same thing happens if you omit the constructor entirely

```
constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.x = '';
    }
```

You can check that this is happening if you for example debug this on the playground:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAiBTSAFYUWAdhAN4CwAUAjUgPZGRQCu8dUAFAJQXW38QAFgEswAOmFFhEYcGTCAXlm4BuKv36wGYOsixjkdAOYchosQBM6AZToBbLGaImuXNXxoBfKutqgmcIiS0rLyStwAXABudMIW7r40-tCBCFa2Dk4uEUySRu7elFQoaBjYkADCIsgWCFgAHthEFmU4EPiEJLz8AA5QwlHA2Aj1OdB5CAC8CADkMwkeCMEycorKXNGxFt0aNBZYIMxGRlhQ7rs0ZuL1U7M6DgBqcsxY84kIhe-p9o4izpG5Zw7XaECDMKBETAia7nWiFT6ULSMRAAT1uRCwAHdMG0qsIaqogA)

You'll have to additionally open the console (F12) to enable the breakpoint being hit

I think the most accurate solution is the one you already presented, basically your parent needs to initialise the property before calling `super()`